# Want to sort a table field from Twig

Tags: templating, sorting

Guess this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to sort a table based on which column the user wants to sort.

Tried:

`{% for row in entry.tablefield|sort %}` (No effect)

`{% for row in entry.tablefield.order('firstName') %}` (Error message)

Anyone who know if this is possible or know how to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the [SuperSort plugin](http://michaelrog.com/craft/lagniappe/supersort)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that with core Craft functionality or Twig filters, but as Mats already suggested in the comments, you can do it with a plugin like ["Super Sort"](http://michaelrog.com/craft/lagniappe/supersort).

The template code to sort the array returned from the table field with that plugin would be:

```
{% for row in entry.tablefield|supersort('sortAs', '{{ object.firstName }}') %}
```